# When I add <!doctype html> to my page the CSS doesn't seem to work and the page looks worse

Tags: css, internet-explorer, doctype, quirks-mode

My problem is that on firefox and chrome my website looks fine in quirks mode, but not in IE.  I realise that I should add  to the start of my page and go from there - but when I do this the website looks the same in all browsers, but not as I want it to.

Here is My website with [DOCTYPE](http://www.biolonline.co.uk/doctype.php) and here is My website in quirks [mode](http://www.biolonline.co.uk) which is how I want it to look (in chrome/firefox)

Is this a problem with my CSS?  I have validated it and no errors were found!

Here is my CSS: http://www.biolonline.co.uk/mystyle.css

Comment: The links to the page html seem to be broken.

Comment: You mean you have been designing your web site without the doctype all the while?

Comment: Yes, I designed the website without DOCTYPE and then when I add doctype it doesn't look right.  Oh yes the links aren't working, I will edit them now.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is (as you rightly guessed in the tags) a thing called Quirks Mode.

If you write a site without a doctype, browsers will render it in Quirks mode. This basically an emulation mode for the browser to pretend to be an older browser for compatibility with old websites.

There's no easy way out of this: If you've designed your site to look good in quirks mode then you've done it wrong and you're going to have to fix it.

Leaving it in quirks mode isn't an option because IE renders differently in this mode to everyone else; your site will look broken in other browsers with or without the doctype.

Sorry to bear bad news.

The main difference between quirks mode and standards mode is the "box model". This defines how margins and borders are treated in terms of the box width and height. In quirks mode, the margin and borders are inside the box, so the `width` is the entire space the box takes up, whereas in standards mode, the margins and borders are added outside the box, so the space the box takes up in total is the `width` plus the `margin` and `border` on either side. This obviously has a big impact on the page layout. There are other differences, but that is the one which will cause the most problems for you.

There is a CSS feature called ['box-sizing'](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing). This allows you to switch the box model between the two modes described above, while staying in standards mode.

This is actually the perfect solution for you: All you need to do is simply put `box-sizing:border-box;` into your CSS for every element (use the `*` selector), and problem solved.

Unfortunately, `box-sizing` is only supported in more recent versions of IE. If you need to support IE6 or IE7, then you're out of luck. If your lowest browser is IE8, then you can use it, and this will solve most of your quirks mode layout problems. Not all of them, but most of them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Does that mean add * { box-sizing:border-box; } to the start of my CSS?  or add box-sizing:border-box; to every single element?  I have added * { box-sizing:border-box; } and had no difference at www.biolonline.co.uk/doctype.php -  If this box-sizing fixes the problem it would be great!!

Comment: @user1527487: yes, `* {box-sizing:border-box;}` should work. It **won't fix everything wrong with quirksmode** though, so your real problem remains. You haven't specified which version of IE you're testing with; note that Box-sizing doesn't work in anything earlier than IE8. (also if it is IE8, check that it's in IE8 mode, and not IE7-compatibility mode, which will further complicate things, and prevent box-sizing from working)

Comment: I'm working with IE9.  However, I have added this and there is no difference (well no good difference) - the navigation bar is smaller at the top!  Here is the page I am testing with http://www.biolonline.co.uk/doctype.php
and the CSS for this page is http://www.biolonline.co.uk/doctype.css
Whilst www.biolonline.co.uk is the page that I am not editing and what I want it to look like.  Thanks for your help.  It is greatly appreciated.